# Difference between overlap for the pool and for the tasks

Tags: overlap, toloka

Some tasks have an overlap value that differs from the overlap for the pool. Why is it different? Can anyone help and explain it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of possible reasons why the overlap value changed for individual tasks:

o The overlap was changed when labeling the pool.

o The pool contains a quality control rule that increases the overlap for rejected tasks or banned users.

o Incremental relabeling is set up in the pool.

o Tasks are uploaded using the API with an overlap set for each task.

In this case, it takes priority over the overlap specified in the pool settings.